# How to pack spheres in python?

Tags: python, optimization, mathematical-optimization, packing

I am trying to model random closed packing spheres of uniform size in a square using python. **And the spheres should not overlap**  but I do not know how to do this

I have so far:
[image]

Code:

```
import random, math, pylab

def show_conf(L, sigma, title, fname):
    pylab.axes()
    for [x, y] in L:
        for ix in range(-1, 2):
            for iy in range(-1, 2):
                cir = pylab.Circle((x + ix, y + iy), radius=sigma,  fc='r')
                pylab.gca().add_patch(cir)
    pylab.axis('scaled')
    pylab.xlabel('eixo x')
    pylab.ylabel('eixo y')
    pylab.title(title)
    pylab.axis([0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0])
    pylab.savefig(fname)
    pylab.close()

L = []
N = 8 ** 2

for i in range(N):
    posx = float(random.uniform(0, 1))
    posy = float(random.uniform(0, 1))
    L.append([posx, posy])

print L

N = 8 ** 2
eta = 0.3
sigma = math.sqrt(eta / (N * math.pi))
Q = 20
ltilde = 5*sigma

N_sqrt = int(math.sqrt(N) + 0.5)


titulo1 = '$N=$'+str(N)+', $\eta =$'+str(eta)
nome1 = 'inicial'+'_N_'+str(N) + '_eta_'+str(eta) + '.png'
show_conf(L, sigma, titulo1, nome1)
```

Comment: You should check out LIGGGHTS, it's designed to simulate exactly what you need

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a very hard problem (and probably **np-hard**). There should be a lot of ressources available.

Before i present some more general approach, check out [this wikipedia-site](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing_in_a_square) for an overview of the currently best known packing-patterns for some N (N circles in a square).

You are lucky that there is an existing circle-packing implementation in python (**heuristic!**) which is heavily based on modern optimization-theory ([difference of convex-functions](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/sloan-school-of-management/15-097-prediction-machine-learning-and-statistics-spring-2012/projects/MIT15_097S12_proj5.pdf) + [Concave-convex-procedure](http://papers.nips.cc/paper/2125-the-concave-convex-procedure-cccp.pdf)).

- The method used is described [here](https://stanford.edu/~boyd/papers/dccp.html) (academic paper & link to software; 2016!)
- The software package used is [here](https://github.com/cvxgrp/dccp)

  - There is an example directory with `circle_packing.py` (which is posted below together with the output)
- The following example also works for circles of different shapes

#### Example taken from the above software-package (example by Xinyue Shen)

```
__author__ = 'Xinyue'
from cvxpy import *
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import dccp

n = 10
r = np.linspace(1,5,n)

c = Variable(n,2)
constr = []
for i in range(n-1):
    for j in range(i+1,n):
        constr.append(norm(c[i,:]-c[j,:])>=r[i]+r[j])
prob = Problem(Minimize(max_entries(max_entries(abs(c),axis=1)+r)), constr)
#prob = Problem(Minimize(max_entries(normInf(c,axis=1)+r)), constr)
prob.solve(method = 'dccp', ccp_times = 1)

l = max_entries(max_entries(abs(c),axis=1)+r).value*2
pi = np.pi
ratio = pi*sum_entries(square(r)).value/square(l).value
print "ratio =", ratio
print prob.status

# plot
plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
circ = np.linspace(0,2*pi)
x_border = [-l/2, l/2, l/2, -l/2, -l/2]
y_border = [-l/2, -l/2, l/2, l/2, -l/2]
for i in xrange(n):
    plt.plot(c[i,0].value+r[i]*np.cos(circ),c[i,1].value+r[i]*np.sin(circ),'b')
plt.plot(x_border,y_border,'g')
plt.axes().set_aspect('equal')
plt.xlim([-l/2,l/2])
plt.ylim([-l/2,l/2])
plt.show()
```

#### Output

[image]

#### Modification for your task: equal-sized circles

Just replace:

```
r = np.linspace(1,5,n)
```

With:

```
r = [1 for i in range(n)]
```

#### Output

[image]

#### Fun example with 64 circles (this will take some time!)

[image]

Comment: Hello, when I try to execute the circle_packing.py example I receive the following error:

Comment: The question title is about 'spheres', how could this example be modified for 3 dimensions?

Comment: @RobinDeSchepper I had the same question and it seems to be as easy as `c = Variable(n,3)`. You'll need to adapt the plotting, of course.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like a more updated version of @leopold.talirz solution, I suggest you use the following:

```
from cvxpy import *
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import dccp

n = 10
r = np.linspace(1,5,n)

c = Variable(shape=(n,2))
constr = []
for i in range(n-1):
    for j in range(i+1,n):
        constr.append(norm(c[i,:]-c[j,:])>=r[i]+r[j])
prob = Problem(Minimize(max(max(abs(c),axis=1)+r)), constr)
#prob = Problem(Minimize(max_entries(normInf(c,axis=1)+r)), constr)
prob.solve(method = 'dccp', ccp_times = 1)

l = max(max(abs(c),axis=1)+r).value*2
pi = np.pi
ratio = pi*sum(square(r)).value/square(l).value
print("ratio =", ratio)
print(prob.status)

# plot
plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
circ = np.linspace(0,2*pi)
x_border = [-l/2, l/2, l/2, -l/2, -l/2]
y_border = [-l/2, -l/2, l/2, l/2, -l/2]
for i in range(n):
    plt.plot(c[i,0].value+r[i]*np.cos(circ),c[i,1].value+r[i]*np.sin(circ),'b')
plt.plot(x_border,y_border,'g')
plt.axes().set_aspect('equal')
plt.xlim([-l/2,l/2])
plt.ylim([-l/2,l/2])
plt.show()
```